# Having to manually turn the internet off and on, on startup for the internet to work

Tags: linux, linux-mint, wifi, internet

A couple of months back, I dual booted Linux Mint 20.3 with Windows, and I had this annoying bug in which when I'd start my PC, it would show the internet as being connected -- but in reality it wasn't working.

To fix this, I'd have to manually turn off and on the internet.

Here is what I would do...

I would click on the following icon:

[image]

Then, I'd click on this switch control twice:

[image]

Yes, I know it's minor, but these are issues you'd expect to see in some 1990's toy where you'd have to turn things on and off for them to work correctly, not in the greatest FOSS operating system. This issue is so primitive and annoying.

Because of the issue, I moved away from Linux. The amount of bugs I experienced was off putting, and it frustrated me. And from a perspective of a Windows user, this is one of the reasons Linux isn't mainstream for PC's.

Now, I've dual booted Linux Mint 21 again, I hoped that it'd be a fresh start.

For the first couple of days or so, it worked fine, although just today I had this bug in which the internet was on but it wasn't *really* on, so to fix this, I'd have to turn it off and then on again. I tried to restart twice and I still had this bug.

I am asking for help. I don't feel like going back to Windows because I see potential for Linux, but at the same time, I hate the amount of bugs in Linux. I really want this issue fixed so I can have a smooth experience again.

I am desperate for any tips as to how I can fix this :( I have not seen anyone ask a similar question, which surprised me, so any help in regards to this would be appreciated.

More details that someone in the comments asked for:

```
tom@TO:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bc2:ac19 Seagate RSS LLC BUP Slim
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 03f0:0024 HP, Inc KU-0316 Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1307:0165 Transcend Information, Inc. 2GB/4GB/8GB Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
tom@TO:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 10th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CometLake-S GT2 [UHD Graphics 630] (rev 03)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-V USB Controller
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-V HECI Controller
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 400 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a3e9 (rev f0)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a392 (rev f0)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a393 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port 9 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation B460 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Memory controller
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-V cAVS
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-V SMBus Host Controller
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

More info:

```
ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fc:34:97:17:cb:ec brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.105/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp3s0
       valid_lft 80991sec preferred_lft 80991sec
    inet6 fd00::80c5:5179:63bb:dabe/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 121sec preferred_lft 31sec
    inet6 fd00::6396:1cef:eacc:8cc/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 121sec preferred_lft 31sec
    inet6 fe80::febd:3faa:176f:41f3/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:e7:0d:72 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**Bounty**

I bountied this question because I am sick of dealing with this annoying issue and I want to draw more attention to the question.

Comment: During the time you're trying to use Linux are you also booting the machine into Windows?  Or are you only booting into Linux?

Comment: I am only booting into Linux via Grub, not sure how you can boot into two operating systems at once lol.

Comment: You can boot and select Linux and then reboot and select Windows.  I was interested in the possibility that Windows interacts with your LAN's DHCP server in a way that makes the server not respond when you reboot and Linux requests DHCP.

Comment: @SottoVoce I don't boot into Windows though, so I am unsure how this can happen.

Comment: this is why I asked.  Your question opens with saying you configured dual boot with Windows and Linux, then didn't say you boot exclusively Linux now.

Comment: What I meant is that I have the ability to switch between Windows and Linux @SottoVoce

Comment: Try to switch off the ipv6 first.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you are suffering from a variant of the problem described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/954236/wired-network-connection-keeps-dropping-out-dual-boot.

The selected answer there has the user install a newer ethernet driver for the same chipset in Ubuntu (the base of Mint), and another has them install ifplugd to cause the OS to reload network config each time it sees a link change.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the router has some conflict between the DHCP lease associated with Windows and with Linux.
If you change your MAC address under Linux, it will appear as a completely different device and potentially correct the issue.

Answer (score -1):

As a temporary solution, you could restart the NetworkManager service.

```
$ sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

In order to run this command as root and on boot, you could create a service which will run your script on startup, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58302378/run-bash-script-as-root-in-startup-on-ubuntu-18-04). To create the script you'll use in your startup service you can runthe following commands:

```
$ cat > restartnetwork << EOF
#!/bin/bash
systemctl restart NetworkManager
EOF
$ chmod +x ./restartnetwork
$ sudo mv ./restartnetwork /usr/bin/
```

Then you can use the path /usr/bin/restartnetwork as the path of your exec within the service file you'll create.

In general, it's pretty difficult otherwise to resolve the underlying issue without more information. To me it sounds like your computer might not retrieve an IP from your default gateway. Check the output of the following command on boot:

```
ip a
```

This should list all of your interfaces. Restart your network and run it again. Compare the outputs - this might lead you in some useful direction.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't address the underlying problem

Comment: @roaima I've tried to give some useful guidance. The OP provided very little information

Comment: @qjxpsrgwp I added more information, plus what other information do you want me to add. Communicate with me.